# How to Login user With OTP Verification using firebase in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, native

Now, I am implement this Code but now i am getting Errors

## [Error: [auth/missing-client-identifier] This request is missing a valid app identifier, meaning that Play Integrity checks, and reCAPTCHA checks were unsuccessful. Please try again, or check the logcat for more details.]

so How to Push OTP and verify it using firebase?

App.js file:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, Text, TextInput, Button } from 'react-native';
import auth from '@react-native-firebase/auth';

const OTPLoginScreen = () => {
  const [phoneNumber, setPhoneNumber] = useState('');

  const sendOtp = async () => {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber('+91'+phoneNumber);
      setVerificationId(confirmation.verificationId);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <View>
      <Text>Enter your phone number:</Text>
      <TextInput
        placeholder="Phone Number"
        value={phoneNumber}
        onChangeText={setPhoneNumber}
      />
      <Button title="Send OTP" onPress={sendOtp} />
    </View>
  );
};

export default OTPLoginScreen;
```